# Flat List not re-rendering even when I change a state

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Expo-cli: 2.2.0

React-Navigation: 2.18.0

I have the following two screens for React Navigation, where one is to input the form details and another is the screen where the user can either edit on the submissions or confirm.

My Input interface looks like this:

```
export default class PickDropInterface extends
 React.Component<NavigationProps<>> {

     this.state = { tasks: [],
     }

 onSubmit = () => { this.props.navigation.navigate("Confirmation",
 {tasks: this.state.tasks, deleteItem: this.deleteItem.bind(this)}); }

deleteItem = (key) => { var filteredTasks =
this.state.tasks.filter(function (item) {   return (item.key !==key);
 });

 render() { 

 return ( 

 <ItemDetail onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />  )  }
```

My Confirmation screen looks like this:

```
export default class Confirmation extends React.Component<NavigationProps<>> { 

this.state={
    refresh: false,
  }

deleteItem = (key) => {
this.props.navigation.state.params.deleteItem(key);
 this.setState({
   refresh: !this.state.refresh
 })
}

_renderItem =({ item }) =>
(
<View style={styles.cardStyle}>
 <Button
    primary
    label="Delete" onPress= {() => {this.deleteItem(item.key)}} /></View>
  )

render() { 

return ( 
<FlatList data={task}
          renderItem= {this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor= {(item) => item.key.toString()}
          extraData={this.state} /> 
)
}
```

Expected Output:

The delete button to prompt refresh in the FlatList and show the new Task list.

Current Output:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmrurTBQpak&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why FlatList didn't re-render, but I found a much simpler solution to what I wanted.

I used conditional rendering instead and I kind of think it's the way to do it instead of navigating to the other screen.

What I did is:

**I made a new state called 'orderComplete' and set it to false as default.**

**Whenever, it is 'false', I made inputInterface above to render whereas it was 'true', I made the above ConfirmationScreen render.**

More on Conditional Rendering can be found in [React's official documentation.](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

FlatList above works like a charm now.